# How to use external terminal like xterm instead of the internal one in Clion Debugging?

Tags: ncurses, clion

Just like the title.I'm writing an game which is using ncurses.External terminal doesn't work correctly.
I tried to look for the setting in Clion but nothing was found.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to execute a CLion program in gnome terminal?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36675012/how-to-execute-a-clion-program-in-gnome-terminal)

Answer (score 0):

Here you can find how to [execute a clion C program in an external terminal](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43440347/5254684)
the only difference is that you have to replace the executable path of **gnome-terminal** with your path to **xterm**.

Another option is remote debugging as it's supported by clion since 2016.1 version.
check out the [official jetbrain blog](https://blog.jetbrains.com/clion/2016/01/attach-to-local-process/) or the [official youtube tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2R3OSGmUmoU).